# Ioc/DI in Java that supports interface resolving

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ioc-container

Coming from DotNet and using "Unity" for Dependency Injection and Dependency Resolution, I would have something like this:

```
public interface ILog
{
    void LogSomething(string msg);
}

public class MyLogger() : ILog
{
    public void LogSomething(string msg)
    {
        /* do something real here */
        Console.Writeline("I'm logging something: " + msg);
    }       
}


public interface IAnimal
{
    void MakeNoise();
}

public class Dog() : IAnimal
{
    private readonly ILog Logger;

    public Dog(ILog lgr)
    {
        this.Logger = lgr;
    }

    public void MakeNoise()
    {
        this.Logger.LogSomething("Bark Bark Bark");
    }       
}


public interface IVehicle
{
    int GetWheelCount();
}

public class Car() : IVehicle
{
    private readonly ILog Logger;

    public Car(ILog lgr)
    {
        this.Logger = lgr;
    }

    public int GetWheelCount()
    {
        return 4;
        this.Logger.LogSomething("GetWheelCount is returning 4");
    }       
}



IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<ILog, MyLogger>();
container.RegisterType<IAnimal, Dog>();
container.RegisterType<IVehicle, Car>();


IAnimal animal = container.Resolve<IAnimal>();
animal.MakeNoise();
IVehicle veh = container.Resolve<IVehicle>();
int wheelCount = veh.GetWheelCount();
```

Note that I only had to register the ILog one time.
And Unity did the magic of getting the constructor injection to work...when I called container.Resolve for either of my 2 objects that depended on an ILog.  And that I am resolving the INTERFACE, not a concrete.

Now I'm trying to do the same in Java.

However, when I use Spring, I'm finding the following.

First, the Java.............with a "real" Logger.

```
 /* not my code........but portion shown here to show interface */
package org.apache.commons.logging;

public interface Log {
    public void info(Object message);
}







public interface IAnimal {

    void makeNoise();
}





import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

public class Dog {

    private Log Logger;

    public Dog(Log lgr) {
        this.Logger = lgr;
    }

    public final void makeNoise() {
        this.Logger.info("Bark Bark Bark");
    }
}


public interface IVehicle {

    int getWheelCount();
}



import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

public class Car {

    private Log Logger;

    public Car(Log lgr) {
        this.Logger = lgr;
    }

    public final int getWheelCount() {
        return 4;
        this.Logger.info("getWheelCount is returning 4");
    }
}
```

My xml configuration for Spring.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">


    <bean id="Jdk14LoggerBeanId"
      class="org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger">
        <constructor-arg value="log" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="myVehicleId"
        class="com.mycompany.Car">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="Jdk14LoggerBeanId"/> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="myAnimalId"
        class="com.mycompany.Dog">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="Jdk14LoggerBeanId"/> 
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and the usage.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;



        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        BeanFactory factory = context;

        Car c = context.getBean(Car.class);
        int wc = c.getWheelCount();
        Dog d = context.getBean(Dog.class);
        c.makeNoise();
```

So there are 2 things which don't jive with my personal preferences.

The "resolve" in the java code.........is for the concrete Dog and Car, not an IAnimal or IVehicle.  (yes, I know in java you don't prefix with an "I", but I'm trying to keep the overlap consistent).

in the beans.xml, I have to declare the constructor for both Dog and Car using "constructor-arg".

Whereas in Unity/DotNot, I only have to register the ILog type once time.

I found this nugget in the internet:

https://www.springbyexample.org/examples/core-concepts-dependency-injection-to-the-rescue.html

> No Interface Injection???
>
> Table 1. Dependency Injection Types DI Type   Description Constructor
>   Injection The constructor arguments are injected during instance
>   instantiation.
>
> Setter Injection  This is the most favored method of dependency
>   injection in Spring. Dependencies are “set” in the objects through
>   setter methods defined in a Spring configuration file.
>
> **Interface Injection This is not implemented in Spring currently, but by Avalon. It’s a different type of DI that involves mapping items to
>   inject to specific interfaces.**

Is there a Ioc/DI injection for Java that is closer to Unity/DotNet? (Or I guess, is there a way to do it in Spring that I'm not using/seeing??)

Specifically....where I Register everything one time .. and I resolve the interface, not the concrete?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [hk2](http://javaee.github.io/hk2/).  It does support interface injection in constructors (or anywhere) and also has features like [stub generation](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/extensibility.html#stub-generation) which can be used to generate implementations of interfaces which are useful for testing/mocking